# JavaScript AJAX executes PHP instead of client redirect on uploading a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, file-upload

I've been using a classic form upload with no JavaScript for the past few weeks, but decided that I wanted to have a progress bar and get a bit control of the upload from the uploading page (index.php) with some help of JavaScript.
So I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg&ab_channel=AdamKhoury) and ended up with this code for HTML:

```
<form id="upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="choose_file">
        <span id="status" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Audio File...</span>
        <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept=".mp3,.wav,.ogg" onchange="uploadFile()">
    </div>
</form>
<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:100%;"></progress>
```

And this code for JavaScript:

```
    function Dg (el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = Dg("fileToUpload").files[0];
    if (file.size > 1280000){
        Dg("FileOutput").innerHTML = "It doesn't fit!";
    }

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("fileToUpload", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "uploaded.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}

function progressHandler(e){
    var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
    Dg("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    Dg("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"%";

}

function completeHandler(e){
    Dg("progressBar").value = 0;
    Dg("status").innerHTML = "Redirecting...";
}

function errorHandler(e){
    Dg("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed...";

}

function abortHandler(e){
    Dg("status").innerHTML = "Canceled upload";

}
```

Everything is working, except that the server runs the PHP file instead of the client. The reason I want the user to run the PHP file is:

1. It contains PHP code with "if else" statement which will output echo's for the client.
2. It could be useful for things like replacing titles with for example the file name or the background audio with the file name etc..
3. Error messages looks better in uploaded.php rather than in index.php.

I'm not sure if it is possible to run the classic uploading code including a progress bar?

Before changing the code, I used a simple code like this, but didn't have much control and it looked weird without a progress bar.

```
<form action="uploaded.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="choose_file">
        <span id="status" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Lossless File...</span>
        <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" accept=".mp3,.wav,.ogg" onchange="javascript:this.form.submit()">
    </div>
</form>
```

So the question is. Could I be able to change the code so that the client runs the PHP file instead of the server with including a progress bar and some javascript?
(server will always execute PHP, but the output of the PHP doesn't reach the client.)

Comment: you just put the code from your upload.php into your index.php just change your form action

Comment: @Beginner Yes, that will help me catch it on the same page, but I rather wants to be redirected.

Comment: `Could I be able to change the code so that the client runs the PHP instead of the server `Clients cant run PHP, it's a sever side language.  So that statement makes little sense as the Sever always runs PHP, regardless of it being called by Ajax or not.

Comment: Yes, I just edited that at the end, but I understand what you mean. But will it be possible to parse the results from uploaded.php to for example another PHP ?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Ok, I edited it a bit more. Should probably mention that the PHP file contains both JavaScript and HTML

Comment: well in that case you want to submit it on upload.php and wants to get the form data(s) better ajax for that